# opencv-3.0.0 ubuntu 14.04 "nonfree/nonfree.hpp" build error

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

I am trying to implement the SURF algorithm in opencv-3.0.0
For it I have included the header files

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>
#include "opencv2/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/features2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d.hpp"
#include "opencv2/calib3d.hpp"
#include <opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>
using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
```

but I keep getting the error mentioned below. I have tried searching everywhere but couldn't find any solution. I have already build the opencv module with extra dependencies.

```
In file included from /usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp:46:0,
             from panaroma.cpp:7:
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:73:21: error: ‘vector’ has not been declared
                 vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints) const;
                 ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:73:27: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
                 vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints) const;
                       ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:77:21: error: ‘vector’ has not been declared
                 vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints,
                 ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:77:27: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
                 vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints,
                       ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:76:10: error: ‘void cv::SIFT::operator()(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, int) const’ cannot be overloaded
 void operator()(InputArray img, InputArray mask,
      ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:72:10: error: with ‘void cv::SIFT::operator()(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, int) const’
 void operator()(InputArray img, InputArray mask,
      ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:81:5: error: ‘AlgorithmInfo’ does not name a type
 AlgorithmInfo* info() const;
 ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:83:49: error: ‘vector’ has not been declared
 void buildGaussianPyramid( const Mat& base, vector<Mat>& pyr, int nOctaves ) const;
                                             ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:83:55: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
 void buildGaussianPyramid( const Mat& base, vector<Mat>& pyr, int nOctaves ) const;
                                                   ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:84:33: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
 void buildDoGPyramid( const vector<Mat>& pyr, vector<Mat>& dogpyr ) const;
                             ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:84:39: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
 void buildDoGPyramid( const vector<Mat>& pyr, vector<Mat>& dogpyr ) const;
                                   ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:85:39: error: ‘vector’ does not name a type
 void findScaleSpaceExtrema( const vector<Mat>& gauss_pyr, const vector<Mat>& dog_pyr,
                                   ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:85:45: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
 void findScaleSpaceExtrema( const vector<Mat>& gauss_pyr, const vector<Mat>& dog_pyr,
                                         ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:89:40: error: ‘vector’ has not been declared
 void detectImpl( const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, const Mat& mask=Mat() ) const;
                                    ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:89:46: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
 void detectImpl( const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, const Mat& mask=Mat() ) const;
                                          ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:90:41: error: ‘vector’ has not been declared
 void computeImpl( const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, Mat& descriptors ) const;
                                     ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:90:47: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
 void computeImpl( const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, Mat& descriptors ) const;
                                           ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:125:28: error: ‘vector’ has not been declared
                 CV_OUT vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints) const;
                        ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:125:34: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
                 CV_OUT vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints) const;
                              ^
In file included from /usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp:46:0,
             from panaroma.cpp:7:
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:128:28: error: ‘vector’ has not been declared
                 CV_OUT vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints,
                        ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:128:34: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
                 CV_OUT vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints,
                              ^
 /usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:127:10: error: ‘void cv::SURF::operator()(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, int) const’ cannot be overloaded
 void operator()(InputArray img, InputArray mask,
      ^
 In file included from /usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp:46:0,
             from panaroma.cpp:7:
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:124:10: error: with ‘void cv::SURF::operator()(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, int) const’
 void operator()(InputArray img, InputArray mask,
      ^
In file included from /usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp:46:0,
             from panaroma.cpp:7:
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:132:5: error: ‘AlgorithmInfo’ does not name a type
 AlgorithmInfo* info() const;
 ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:142:40: error: ‘vector’ has not been declared
 void detectImpl( const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, const Mat& mask=Mat() ) const;
                                    ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:142:46: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
 void detectImpl( const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, const Mat& mask=Mat() ) const;
                                          ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:143:41: error: ‘vector’ has not been declared
 void computeImpl( const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, Mat& descriptors ) const;
                                     ^
/usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp:143:47: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘<’ token
 void computeImpl( const Mat& image, vector<KeyPoint>& keypoints, Mat& descriptors ) const;
                                           ^
```

**EDIT 1**
So, the issue I was actually facing was that I was trying to use the package which was in development and not stable version. I just had to do `git checkout 3.0.0` to get to the stable version.

Comment: what's your compiler?

Comment: try replacing `opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp` with `opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp`

Comment: Please check the new problem I face [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33602898/opencv-contrib-installation-error-ubuntu-14-04) @Azad

Answer (score 0):

Open the file features2d.hpp located at /usr/include/opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp
You should be a sudo usr to edit the file.
Add the "vector" header file as #include < vector >
and then add using namespace std;

This should solve your problem.
regards,
Avinash