# opencv_contrib compilation error: class has no member

Tags: c++, opencv, ubuntu

I have to implement the SURF algorithm for image stitching. I was having trouble with the libraries, as listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33560251/opencv-3-0-0-ubuntu-14-04-nonfree-nonfree-hpp-build-error)

After trying the solutions I could find, I removed the opencv and started to build from scratch. I tried to include the 'opencv_contrib' library during installation, but it didn't work.

So I installed opencv, and then tried to integrate the package as told int he [github repository](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib) of the package. During the
    make -j2 
line, I keep getting the following error.

```
[ 77%] Building CXX object modules/ximgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_ximgproc.dir/src/sparse_match_interpolators.cpp.o
In file included from /home/akshat/OpenCV/opencv-3.0.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core.hpp:54:0,
                 from /home/akshat/OpenCV/opencv-3.0.0/build/modules/ximgproc/precomp.hpp:40:
/home/akshat/opencv_contrib/modules/ximgproc/src/sparse_match_interpolators.cpp: In member function ‘virtual void cv::ximgproc::EdgeAwareInterpolatorImpl::interpolate(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, cv::OutputArray)’:
/home/akshat/opencv_contrib/modules/ximgproc/src/sparse_match_interpolators.cpp:171:52: error: ‘const class cv::_InputArray’ has no member named ‘isVector’
     CV_Assert( !from_points.empty() && from_points.isVector() &&
                                                    ^
/home/akshat/OpenCV/opencv-3.0.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:389:33: note: in definition of macro ‘CV_Assert’
 #define CV_Assert( expr ) if(!!(expr)) ; else cv::error( cv::Error::StsAssert, #expr, CV_Func, __FILE__, __LINE__ )
                                 ^
/home/akshat/opencv_contrib/modules/ximgproc/src/sparse_match_interpolators.cpp:172:52: error: ‘const class cv::_InputArray’ has no member named ‘isVector’
                !to_points  .empty() && to_points  .isVector() &&
                                                    ^
/home/akshat/OpenCV/opencv-3.0.0/modules/core/include/opencv2/core/base.hpp:389:33: note: in definition of macro ‘CV_Assert’
 #define CV_Assert( expr ) if(!!(expr)) ; else cv::error( cv::Error::StsAssert, #expr, CV_Func, __FILE__, __LINE__ )
                                 ^
make[2]: *** [modules/ximgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_ximgproc.dir/src/sparse_match_interpolators.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [modules/ximgproc/CMakeFiles/opencv_ximgproc.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Now I'm confused. Please fill in the gaps in the information. 1)why did you "remove" opencv? Was it installed as a binary package before? 2)elaborate on your steps: 2.1)What versions are you using, from where (if it's not _the_ official release at _the_ offical site)? 2.2)on "I tried to include the 'opencv_contrib' library during installation, but it didn't work." and "installed opencv" - unsure what that means. "install" without specification means installing a pre-built package from a repository...

Comment: ...3) "tried to integrate the package as told" - the readme on the link tells about building `opencv` _with_ the extra modules compiled-in. But you're saying that you're only building the extra modules, separately?

Comment: I had installed opencv by executing the shell file given [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenCV). Then while searching for how to install opencv_contrib, I came across the link which told me to install it while setting up opencv. So, I uninstalled opencv. While trying to install with the opencv_contrib module, I was getting error while building the code( i don't remember it exactly, but the error was shown and then it asked me if I wanted to create a new Debian package, which again resulted in error).

Comment: So, I tried to install opencv seperately and now I an trying to install the package by going into the opencv/build and building the opencv_contrib module there. shown [here](https://github.com/Itseez/opencv_contrib#how-to-build-opencv-with-extra-modules)

Comment: Okay, this makes it clearer. You indeed build thgem together, and prior installations don't appear to be affecting you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
/home/akshat/opencv_contrib/modules/ximgproc/src/sparse_match_interpolators.cpp:171:52: error: ‘const class cv::_InputArray’ has no member named ‘isVector’
```

testifies this is a version incompatibility. The code in `ximgproc` expects a different interface from `cv` (specifically, `cv::_InputArray`) than the one your stock one is providing.

Your options here are:

- try the version of the `opencv-contrib` codebase that corresponds to your installed version of `cv`
- make yet another attempt to build the newer `cv` that corresponds to your current `opencv-contrib`

Comment: I downloaded both the packages last night only. So as per my knowledge, they both are latest

Comment: "both latest" doesn't mean "of compatible (or even workable) versions", especially if it's git heads rather than release snapshots. Pls update the quesiton as per my requests above for me to be able deduce if this is the case.

Comment: Yeah, you were right, I don't use Github so didn't know that I was actually building in a different branch.

Comment: Thanks to you, too. You beat me to the punch and thus saved us both time and effort.

Comment: if someone needs more exact solutions, I solved it by issuing `git checkout 3.0.0` in both folders, i.e. in `opencv` and in `opencv_contrib` and then recompiling